# Determine asymptotic distribution and efficiency of an estimator

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I have the following problem:

Let $X_1,..., X_n$ be a sample of independent, identically distributed random variables, with density $$f_{\theta}(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{\theta-x}, & \text{if } x\geq \theta\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases}$$

Let $\hat\theta_n$ be the maximum-likelihood estimator (MLE) of $\theta$. I am asked to find the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt n (\hat\theta_n-\theta)$ and $\hat\theta_n$ efficiency.

So far, I computed the MLE, which is $\hat\theta_n=min\{x_i\}$, for $i=0,...,n.$. I also know that if I find that $\sqrt n (\hat\theta_n-\theta)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,I(\theta))$, we would have both the asymptotic distribution and efficiency of the estimator.

Central Limit Theorem could be a way to do it, but I'm really struggling on it.

Any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: This MLE is not asymptotically normal. Also pdf should have $x>\theta$ instead.

Comment: There was a mistake in the pdf, the first case is if $x\geq\theta$. If it's not normal, which is the asymptotic distribution then?

Comment: $n(\hat\theta_n-\theta)$ is exactly distributed as $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$, which is what I would also call the asymptotic distribution of the MLE $\hat\theta_n$.

Comment: That, in fact, is something I also want to prove later. But how can I get there is my question.

Comment: Pdf of $\hat\theta_n$ is $ne^{n(\theta-x)}$, right?

Comment: Yes, for $x>\theta$.

Comment: Then I see the estimator follows an $Exp(1)$ distribution, as it can be split into $ne^{n\theta} \cdot e^{-x}$, which is $k\cdot Exp(1)$, but how can I get the asymptotic distribution asked and discuss MLE efficiency?

Comment: I mean, isn't $\hat\theta_n$ distributed as $ne^{n\theta} \cdot Exp(1)$, and therefore, $n(\hat\theta_n-\theta)$ as $n^2e^{n\theta} \cdot Exp(1) - n\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you are asked, find the distribution function of $T=\sqrt n(\hat\theta_n-\theta)$.

Now $\hat\theta_n$ has CDF $$P(\hat\theta_n\le t)=\begin{cases} 1-e^{-n(t-\theta)} &,\text{ if }t\ge\theta \\ 0&,\text{ if }t<\theta \end{cases}$$

So CDF of $T$ should be

\begin{align}
F_n(t)&=P\left(\sqrt n(\hat\theta_n-\theta)\le t\right)
\\&=P\left(\hat\theta_n\le \frac{t}{\sqrt n}+\theta\right)
\\&=\begin{cases}1-e^{-\sqrt nt}&,\text{ if }t\ge 0 \\ 0&,\text{ if }t<0\end{cases}
\end{align}

Since $n(\hat\theta_n-\theta)\sim \mathsf{Exp}(1)$, it is clear that $T$ is exponential with mean $1/\sqrt n$.

Taking limit as $n\to\infty$, show that $F_n(t)$ converges to another distribution function. This would give you a *degenerate* asymptotic distribution of the MLE $\hat\theta_n$.

To arrive at a *non-degenerate* limiting distribution of the MLE, an appropriate scaling of $\hat\theta_n$ is $T'=n(\hat\theta_n-\theta)$. We know $T'$ is exactly distributed as $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$, which is naturally also the asymptotic distribution.

---

Maximum likelihood estimators are expected to be (asymptotically) efficient in most cases.

Formally, if $T_0$ is the uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator (UMVUE) of $\theta$, then (large sample) efficiency of $\hat\theta_n$ is defined by $\mathrm e=\frac{\operatorname{Var}(T_0)}{\operatorname{Var}(\hat\theta_n)}$. Find $T_0$ and hence conclude $\hat\theta_n$ is indeed efficient.

Comment: in this case is Var(T0) the fisher information? and var (MLE) the denominator, is that the variance of T' distributed as EXP(1) given previously?  this is superefficiency principle right?